# 500 - Internal server error after downgrading to CF11, only for default page

Tags: iis, coldfusion

I just downgraded from CF2018 to CF11 (for debugging purposes) and I now have a problem that's driving me up the wall.  If I go to the home page like this:

/default.cfm

No problem.  But if I go to it like this:

/

I get "500 - Internal server error."  What the heck is going on?  Using Win2012/IIS.

Comment: Detailed Error Information:

Module
   IsapiModule 

Notification
   ExecuteRequestHandler 

Handler
   cfmHandler 

Error Code
   0x8007045a 



Requested URL
   http://[site]:80/default.cfm 

Physical Path
   D:\[path]\webroot\default.cfm 

Logon Method
   Anonymous 

Logon User
   Anonymous

Comment: Please check if `default.cfm` is there in the default documents for the IIS website.

Comment: It is.  If it wasn't, it'd be generating a 403 if browsing isn't enabled, not a 500.  The detailed error info points to the cfmHandler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to manually update all the .cf* handlers in IIS -- they were all pointing to the CF2018 DLL.  Also, I had to delete the CF2018 reference in ISAPI and CGI Restrictions.